# Which is the best way to Compare two documents in Java without any complexity and precise result

Tags: java, hash, compare, hashcode

I have two word documents which i am trying to compare in java .
I tried using

**md5 hashcode**

```
HashCode newFile = Files.asByteSource(newFileInput).hash(Hashing.md5());
HashCode oldFile = Files.asByteSource(oldFileInput).hash(Hashing.md5());
```

and also using,

**boolean isEqual = FileUtils.contentEquals(oldFile , newFile);**

Even though the contents are same ,compared the content using online tools and beyond compare,
still the hashcode in both above method comes as MISMATCH.

any solutions? or way to compare any file type using any API in Java.
i need to do deep compare between two word files as in for spaces,fonts , content. etc..

Expected Result : Both file should match

Comment: Even if the contents superficially "match", the two files don't appear to be binary identical.  You don't specify the file format.  Who knows: maybe they're MS Word files, and they have different "author" names or "date modified" timestamps in the file's metadata.  And no, outside of a "binary comparison", there's absolutely no way to "compare any file type".  In Java, or in any other programming language ;)  You can find a Java library for comparing .pdfs ... but that library won't necessarily be able to compare .jpg images or .mp3 sound clips.

Comment: dont use hash matching for comparison instead implement the comparable and check for the fields you want to match

Comment: @Harkal  no specific field, but the whole file i have to match

Comment: then you can stringify the object and check if the two strings are equal. you can use gson for converting object into string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were multiple suggestions and answers to my question, thanks for that. The reasons for mismatch in docx file is there in the metadata info, everytime we create a doc/docx file, the timestamp changes. Though i tried to change the timestamp(accessed,modified and created) of both the files to make it same and compare, which didn't work out. The reason is apart from these time stamps, there is a meta info called Zip Modify Date, which isn't visible when we see the file properties. this timestamp i found as one of the reason there was mismatch in hashcode. Also, the base64 encoded strings was different because of the zip timestamp.

So, the options i had to do the comparison were :

```
1. converting the docx file to xml file
2. Zip the docx file, unzip it and iterate though all the xml files to find  the hashcode and compare the hascodes.(suggeted as of the answers)
```

"2" was good but it required lot of iterations and unzipping would create lot many folders.

"1" , was straight fwd, as i tried it using external lib -> docx4j , which converted the docx to xml and then i could match the hashcode , it worked.

Convert DOCX to XML file

I had to try different options since i was looking for simplest and not so complex way to compare content and styles of the word document.

Answer (score 2):

Even if both of your documents look the same or even if both contains the same formatted content, a slightly change like the last modified date will result in a failed comparison. JSON documents are more easier to compare but Word documents are binary. The smallest change can change the document completely.

So you have to do it the hard way: Find a library to read the content of the Word files by yourself and check the content of both files specifically.

Comment: yes, there is change in times both files are created, any java lib u are aware of, that can do the job?

Answer (score -1):

Read the files in string and then compare the strings using, you can convert the files in string using stringbuilder or tostring method.
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("manifest.mf");
BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

```
String line = buf.readLine();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        
while(line != null){
   sb.append(line).append("\n");
   line = buf.readLine();
}
```

String fileAsString = sb.toString();
System.out.println("Contents : " + fileAsString);

```
string one = "fdgfhdgkifgh";
string two = "fdgfhdgkifgh";

if(one.Equals(two) || one == two ){
//something
}else{
//not compared
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't looks like Java. Also `one == two` won't work.

Comment: it does try it .

Comment: Did you try to run it in IDE? I am 100% sure code won't compile itself :)

Comment: This won't produce better results since we are working with binary documents.

Answer (score -3):

In Java, you can compare two Strings with string1.equals(string2).

So in your case you need the line newFile.equals(oldFile)

Comment: I hope file comparison would have been that easy :)

Comment: @PradeepSimha  will appreciate that if any solutions that you can suggest